# Show a colour X Window Pixmap in the root window's background

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, x11

I have a got a colour X PixMap file, GCC compiler, a working X server on a display and a very simple task: show an XPM file in colour by a C/C++ program via the X Server running on a display.

I have googled a lot and my brain is completely broken. No information about XCreatePixmapFromData. I can't get in the xloadimage sources. But putting a 1-bit depth bitmat is successfull and I want such an easy solution for a colour pixmap.

Teh pixmap is ordinary and here it is, for example, I just wanna show that it has almost the same structure as an X BitMap file (an array of constant chars) and can be included in the C/C++ program... http://pastebin.com/b5QTrDTH

A simple code example drawing a colour pixmap would be great.

That should be easy, please help!
P. S. sorry, that's my first stackoverflow question.

Comment: Have a look at XCB. It is probably more fun than Xlib. http://xcb.freedesktop.org/colorsandpixmaps/

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function is `XpmCreatePixmapFromData`. It is described e.g. [here](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/formats/xpm.pdf) along with other functions and data structures.

Basically you pass the XPM data and get back two things, a pixmap and a bitmap mask. If your pixmap is rectangular, you may ignore the mask. If not, you use it to set the mask in your GC. Then you use `XCopyArea` to copy from the returned pixmap to the window.

You may pass NULL as the "attributes" argument. If you don't, make sure the value mask is set correctly.

You need to link with the xpm library which you may have to download somewhere. It is not a part of X11 proper.

An example can be found [here](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/xsheep/xsheep/oldsheep.c).